# Custom config files - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i try to create my custom email config file that includes my email server configuration.

i created it under /config directory and
the code is below:

```
<?php

$config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'mertmetinbjk@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => '*************',
            'mailtype' => 'html'
        );




        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

?>
```

and in order to use it i call in my kayit.php's which is a controller constructor

```
 $this->config->load('email');
```

However, i get an error like that
[image]

Comment: On a different note, you might need to create an array with a different name than $config, because the global variable $config is called by the CI backend when initiating classes. You could change $config to $config['myEmailConfig'] in the code above to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 6):

I quote from the manual:

> If you prefer not to set preferences using the above method, you can
>   instead put them into a config file. Simply create a new file called
>   the email.php, add the $config array in that file. Then save the file
>   at config/email.php

The config file is just AN ARRAY (named $config), and being only that it doesn't have access to the $this reference. The code you're using (loading a library, for example) has to be *inside a controller*, **not** inside the config file!

Comment: is it bad idea to keep email settings as a config file ? If it is , what is the best idea for it ?

Comment: No, it's not a bad idea; it might, indeed, be a good one, if you always use the same settings. The point is different, though: the config file is just a file containing an array; any other code is out of place

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a file named `email.php` in `./application/config/` folder and in that file create an array with your values. In your case it should be

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'mertmetinbjk@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '*************',
        'mailtype' => 'html'
    );
```

Now whenever you load the email library in your application it overrides the default configuration with this. Remember the array name must be config.

Comment: You dont need to call your email library as you mentioned $this->config->load('email');  just call that in a standard way like $this->load->library('email');

Comment: Don't actually do `$config = Array(`.  This will remove all other config files (for other libraries or whatever).

Comment: @RocketHazmat it doesnt remove the config array of other files. I am using it in this way.

Answer (score 4):

Since this config file is for the [built-in email class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html), it will be auto-loaded if it's called `config/email.php`.

> If you prefer not to set preferences using the above method, you can
>   instead put them into a config file. Simply create a new file called
>   the `email.php`, add the `$config array` in that file. Then save the file
>   at `config/email.php` and it will be used automatically. You will NOT
>   need to use the `$this->email->initialize()` function if you save your
>   preferences in a config file.

You cannot (why would you) call `$this->load` inside a config file.

Also, you cannot declare config files like that.  `$config = Array(`, you are overwriting all other values in `$config`.  You need to declare each option individually.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'mertmetinbjk@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '*************';
$config['mailtype']= 'html';
```

Answer (score 2):

in your config `/config/email.php`:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'mertmetinbjk@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '*************',
        'mailtype' => 'html'
    );
```

in your controller:

```
$this->config->load('email');
var_dump((array)$this->config); //show all the configs including those in the email.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate methods in the config file because it hasn't loaded the CodeIgniter instance.

Answer (score 1):

Look Codeignitor userGuide http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);


$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();

echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Answer (score 0):

first you can delete a **email.php** file loacate in **config/email.php** .
after try your code.